# Git workflow for Web Developer and Web Designer

Tags: git, workflow

My partner and I are building a web app and I'm looking for suggestions on a git workflow that we can implement. I'm the developer half of this team so I want to keep all of the difficult version control (i.e. merging and pushing to production) under my control but I want my partner - the designer - to be able to start to use git and start to learn some of it's goodness. I don't want a workflow that would be appropriate for a team of developers because I want to handhold my partner through this to get him going with git. What I'm thinking is something like this:

1. Designer clones git from my local machine:

   designer:~/$git clone git://192.168.0.1/programmer/project.git
2. Designer branches and makes changes:

   designer:~/$git co -b designer-branch
3. Designer pushes his branch to my machine:

   designer:~/$git push designer-branch
4. I'll merge the designer-branch into the master:

   programmer:~/$git co master
   programmer:~/$git merge designer-branch
5. I push the changes to our repo:

   programmer:~/$git push

I think this makes the most sense but I'd love any tips or tricks that other developers have when you've tried to bring a designer into the git fold.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I would add is to use feature branches and stay away from trunk-based development. If you are resolving conflicts, share how you resolved them with rerere:

http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html

The rr-cache directory contents can be shared via symlinks to a "helper" repo. This way others can put features together and not require the assistance of the person who originally solved a conflict.

Google "git flow" as well. It automates some of the redundant things you do with branches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I _really_ like git-flow. It looks like it will be a great tool when I add more developers to our team. For right now, I'm going to stay away from it because I don't want to scare my designer ... to much :)